# How do I include role in event grid authentication webhook Azure Acitve Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to set up an authenticated webhook call from an Azure Event Grid Domain subscription to a web app service in the same tenant. I am able to do everything up to a certain point which is that I am trying to tie the authentication to a specific app role in the subscribing app. Currently, the authentication works, but I cannot seem to figure out how to include a specific role in the token that gets sent to the subscribing endpoint. It may be that it's more of a generic question on setting up an enterprise app registration (which event grid uses) with a configurable role for app registrations. My issue is that I know how to do it when there's an app registration, but in this case I only have an enterprise app.

I have followed the documentation, and this article seems to try to do the same thing, but I don't want to do it in powershell as we have an Identity-responsible who is going to do the actual work as well as me wanting to understand what happens behind the scenes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery

Does anybody know how to set up the event grid webhook authentication so it includes a specific role (most probably an app role defined in the manifest of the subscribing app's app registration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are following correct way of configuring event subscription.
The role which you wants to add in application can be done as below -
Azure Portal>>All Services>>Subscription>>Select Subscription>>IAM Role>>Add Role assignment>>1.Select the role which he need  2. Assign access to Azure AD user or Service Principal  3. Select the application >> Save.

or

If need to assign some customise role you can create the custom role as below -
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json

Azure Active Directory to secure the connection between your Event Subscription and your webhook endpoint.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery.md